# Leaflet slider group by year

Tags: jquery-ui, dictionary, slider, gis, leaflet

I'm using leaflet slider - https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider - but I can't get the desired result, even if from the plugin description it seems it can do.

I have a collection of features, geometry type is polygon, where I've inserted a property "time" as requested by the plugin.
I've tried bot with "time":"2014" and "time":"2014-01-01 00:00:00" with no difference.
I have in total 30 features, 10 for 2012, 10 for 2013 and 10 for 2014

What I'm trying to achieve is to show all the polygon of 2012, then 2013 and then 2014, by moving the slider, that should have 3 steps, each year one step.

Instead I get always one polygon at each slider move.
At the beginning I get also all the polygons (30) designed on top of each other, even if I specify "*showAllOnStart: false*"

here is my js code:

```
var geojson;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("urlWhereIretrieveTheJson", function (geoJson) {
            geojson = L.geoJson(geoJson, { style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature }).addTo(map);

            var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
                position: "bottomleft",
                layer: geojson,
                range: false,
                showAllOnStart: false
            });

            map.addControl(sliderControl);
            sliderControl.startSlider();
            ;
        });
    });
```

the json schema is like the following:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{"type":"Feature",
"properties": {"name": "Thies","bl": 6,"**time**": "**2013-01-01 00:00:00+00**"},
"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[....]} 
},{....}
]}
```

Here is a jsFiddle with complete code and datasource:
http://jsfiddle.net/brainsengineering/nboo4ksg/

Comment: any chance of being able to throw this entire setup onto a demo site?

Comment: @snkashis updated with jsFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to one thing that

**I get also all the polygons (30) designed on top of each other, even if I specify "showAllOnStart: false"**

is that you're adding `geojson` this way

```
geojson = L.geoJson(geoJson, { style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature }).addTo(map);
```

don't add `addTo(map)` at the end, simply do this

```
geojson = L.geoJson(geoJson, { style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature });
```

**the other thing is that you want to group your data based on same values** i.e group data for year 2013, 2014 and 2015. For this we need to alter the plugin a bit because currently the plugin don't handle to group data based on same values. So here is the code

```
L.Control.SliderControl = L.Control.extend({
options: {
    position: 'topright',
    layers: null,
    timeAttribute: 'time',
    isEpoch: false,     // whether the time attribute is seconds elapsed from epoch
    startTimeIdx: 0,    // where to start looking for a timestring
    timeStrLength: 19,  // the size of  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss - if millis are present this will be larger
    maxValue: -1,
    minValue: -1,
    showAllOnStart: false,
    markers: null,
    range: false,
    follow: false,
    alwaysShowDate : false,
    rezoom: null
},

initialize: function (options) {
    L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
    this._layer = this.options.layer;

},

extractTimestamp: function(time, options) {
    if (options.isEpoch) {
        time = (new Date(parseInt(time))).toString(); // this is local time
    }
    return time.substr(options.startTimeIdx, options.startTimeIdx + options.timeStrLength);
},

setPosition: function (position) {
    var map = this._map;

    if (map) {
        map.removeControl(this);
    }

    this.options.position = position;

    if (map) {
        map.addControl(this);
    }
    this.startSlider();
    return this;
},

onAdd: function (map) {
    this.options.map = map;

    // Create a control sliderContainer with a jquery ui slider
    var sliderContainer = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'slider', this._container);
    $(sliderContainer).append('<div id="leaflet-slider" style="width:200px"><div class="ui-slider-handle"></div><div id="slider-timestamp" style="width:200px; margin-top:13px; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; border-radius:5px;"></div></div>');
    //Prevent map panning/zooming while using the slider
    $(sliderContainer).mousedown(function () {
        map.dragging.disable();
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        map.dragging.enable();
        //Hide the slider timestamp if not range and option alwaysShowDate is set on false
        if (options.range || !options.alwaysShowDate) {
            $('#slider-timestamp').html('');
        }
    });

    var options = this.options;
    this.options.markers = [];
    this.options.unique_time_values = [];

    //If a layer has been provided: calculate the min and max values for the slider
    if (this._layer) {
        /*var index_temp = 0;
        this._layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            //console.log(layer);
            options.markers[index_temp] = layer;
            ++index_temp;
        });
        options.maxValue = index_temp - 1;
        this.options = options;*/

        var flags = [], unique_values = [],len;
        this._layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

            if( flags[layer.feature.properties.time]) return;
            flags[layer.feature.properties.time] = true;
            unique_values.push(layer.feature.properties.time);
            ++len;

        });
        //console.log(unique_values);

        var all_features = [];
        for (var i=0;i<unique_values.length;i++){
            all_features[i] = [];
        }
        //console.log(all_features);

        //console.log(this._layer.getLayers().length)
        var layers = this._layer.getLayers()
        for(var i=0;i<layers.length;i++){

            //console.log(layers[i].feature.properties.time);
            var index = unique_values.indexOf(layers[i].feature.properties.time)
            //console.log(index);
            all_features[index].push(layers[i]);

        }
        //console.log(all_features);

        for (var i=0;i<all_features.length;i++){
            options.markers[i] = L.featureGroup(all_features[i]);
        }
        options.maxValue = all_features.length - 1;
        this.options = options;
        this.options.unique_time_values = unique_values

    } else {
        console.log("Error: You have to specify a layer via new SliderControl({layer: your_layer});");
    }
    return sliderContainer;
},

onRemove: function (map) {
    //Delete all markers which where added via the slider and remove the slider div
    for (i = this.options.minValue; i < this.options.maxValue; i++) {
        map.removeLayer(this.options.markers[i]);
    }
    $('#leaflet-slider').remove();
},

startSlider: function () {
    _options = this.options;
    _extractTimestamp = this.extractTimestamp
    var index_start = _options.minValue;
    if(_options.showAllOnStart){
        index_start = _options.maxValue;
        if(_options.range) _options.values = [_options.minValue,_options.maxValue];
        else _options.value = _options.maxValue;
    }
    $("#leaflet-slider").slider({
        range: _options.range,
        value: _options.minValue,
        values: _options.values,
        min: _options.minValue,
        max: _options.maxValue,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (e, ui) {
            var map = _options.map;
            var fg = L.featureGroup();
            if(!!_options.markers[ui.value]) {
                //console.log('inside');
                // If there is no time property, this line has to be removed (or exchanged with a different property)
                if(_options.markers[ui.value].feature !== undefined) {
                    if(_options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties[_options.timeAttribute]){
                        if(_options.markers[ui.value]) $('#slider-timestamp').html(
                            _extractTimestamp(_options.unique_values[ui.value].feature.properties[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
                    }else {
                        console.error("Time property "+ _options.timeAttribute +" not found in data");
                    }
                }else {
                    // set by leaflet Vector Layers
                    if(_options.unique_time_values[ui.value]){
                        if(_options.markers[ui.value]) $('#slider-timestamp').html(
                            _extractTimestamp(_options.unique_time_values[ui.value], _options));
                    }else {
                        console.error("Time property "+ _options.timeAttribute +" not found in data");
                    }
                }

                var i;
                // clear markers
                for (i = _options.minValue+1; i <= _options.maxValue; i++) {
                    if(_options.markers[i]) map.removeLayer(_options.markers[i]); 
                }
                if(_options.range){
                    // jquery ui using range
                    for (i = ui.values[0]; i <= ui.values[1]; i++){
                       if(_options.markers[i]) {
                           map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                           fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                       }
                    }
                }else if(_options.follow){
                    for (i = ui.value - _options.follow + 1; i <= ui.value ; i++) {
                        if(_options.markers[i]) {
                            map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                            fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    for (i = _options.minValue; i <= ui.value ; i++) {
                        if(_options.markers[i]) {
                            map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                            fg.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            if(_options.rezoom) {
                map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds(), {
                    maxZoom: _options.rezoom
                });
            }
        }
    });
    if (!_options.range && _options.alwaysShowDate) {
        $('#slider-timestamp').html(_extractTimeStamp(_options.markers[index_start].feature.properties[_options.timeAttribute], _options));
    }
    for (i = _options.minValue; i < index_start; i++) {
        _options.map.addLayer(_options.markers[i]);
    }
}
});

L.control.sliderControl = function (options) {
    return new L.Control.SliderControl(options);
};
```

Just remove the link to current source of the plugin and use the code provided above in place of plugin file and it'd work. Tell me if you face any problem, so i'll create a `fiddle` for you as well.

**Note: As I've modified the code for your specific case, it might not work in other scenarios**

Comment: Only one problem: it doesn't remove "old" polygon but it overlap: if I select 2015, I see 2013, 2014 and 2015 on top of each other. I'm trying to modify the code to remove them all

Comment: just pass the `follow:true ` as a parameter when you call the `sliderControl` in place of `range:false`. Hope it'd work

Comment: unable to get the alwaysShowDate property to work after I tweaked the code with your solution .. any idea how to resolve it ?